# angular import html return object

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I've updated my web application to meteor 1.5. Now when i import a template in an angular component:

import template from './template.html'

Returns an object and the template is inside the default property

```
Object {default: '<div class="m-t-100" ui-view=""></div>', Symbol(__esModule): true}
```

Before i updated the web application the import returned a String with the content of template.html

```
'<navigation ng-if="home.isLoggedIn"></navigation>…menu-app> <div class="m-t-100" ui-view=""></div>'
```

I want to know what makes this change

The code is:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import ngMaterial from 'angular-material';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import template from './home.html';

class Home {  
  constructor($scope,$reactive,$urlRouter) {
    'ngInject';    
    $reactive(this).attach($scope);   

    console.log(template);

    //Helpers
    this.helpers({      
      isLoggedIn() {        
        return !!Meteor.userId();
      }
    });                

    $urlRouter.sync();
    $urlRouter.listen();    
  }   
}

const name = 'home';

// create a module
export default angular.module(name, [
  angularMeteor,
  ngMaterial,
  uiRouter,   
]).component(name, {
  template:template,
  controllerAs: name,
  controller: Home  
})
  .config(config)    
  .run(run);

function config($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

}

function run($rootScope, $state) {
  'ngInject';

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
    (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) => {
      if (error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
        $state.go('login');
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Thanks!,

Comment: I think, it's a problem with the package standard-minifier-js@2.1.0